# Accessing a class method

Tags: php

My class:

```
class mvc {
    public function home () {
        return 'index';
    }
}
```

object:

```
include "./sys/controller/".$Current_page_Controller_name.".php";

        // making object of the controller class.
            $controller = new $Current_page_Controller_name;

        // Cheks if model is called, m stands for "model"
            if (isset($_GET['m'])) {

            }

            $method_name = $mvc->$Current_page_Controller_name.'()';

    // Cheks if default model exists, if not gives an error.
        if (method_exists($controller, $method_name)) {
            echo "+";
        } else {
            echo "-";
            //die("Lappas sledzis saplisis, gaidiet drizuma... (2)");
        }
```

I keepgetting this error

```
Notice: Undefined property: mvc::$home in /home/unusuallv/domains/.../public_html/sys/config.php on line 51
```

the problem is near $method_name = $mvc->$Current_page_Controller_name.'()'; i know it, but i cant figure it out:// tnx a lot !

Comment: Why do you call the upper part a class and the lower part an object?

Comment: instead of $mvc->$Current_page_Controller_name.'()' use $mvc->$Current_page_Controller_name()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the following expression:

```
$method_name = $mvc->$Current_page_Controller_name.'()';
```

The `->` operator has higher precedence than the string concatenation operator (`.`). This means that PHP evaluates the expression `$mvc->$Current_page_Controller_name` first, so it tries to access the home property of the mvc class (which does not exist).

Use this instead:

```
$method_name = $mvc->$Current_page_Controller_name();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling that function, that's the error. You don't want to call it, but get its name. To do so, you don't need to `$method_name = $mvc->$Current_page_Controller_name.'()';` but rather `$method_name=Current_page_Controller_name;` and then call it like that: `$mvc->$method_name()`.

When PHP is processing your script, it considers `$mvc->$Current_page_Controller_name.'()'` as you were accessing variable from `$mvc` and then, appending to it string `'()'`.

Consider these examplees:

```
//somewhere file
class MVC{
public $someVar="QWERTY";
public function abc(){/*...*/}
public function parseResponse(){/*...*/}
};
///.....
$mvc=new MVC;
$abc="someVar";
$x=$mvc->$abc."()";
echo $x;//gives you "QWERTY()"

$b=method_exists($mvc,$abc);//false
$b=method_exists($mvc,'abc');//true
//call function
$abc="parseResponse";
$mvc->$abc();//calls MVC::parseResponse
```

Comment: you misundersund me, $Current_page_Controller_name is function name in mvc class. I need to acces it ://

Comment: Before you added the example, the answer was ok, now you made it bad by providing a very suboptimal example with errors.

Comment: You're defining a variable $someFunc but call it Func for Function, call it someVar, if anything.

Comment: I've checked the code, gives no error, everything is as commented.

Comment: @user1609394 I've added example how to call the function which name is stored in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
$method_name = $mvc->$Current_page_Controller_name.'()';
```

Should be this:

```
$method_name = $mvc->$Current_page_Controller_name();
```